# Table with FIXED number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and would like to know if there is a way to contain only certain number of records in a table. Old records will be automatically replaced with newer ones.

For example table1 should and always contain 100 records. Newer records will be replaced with older ones. The count in the number of records in a table at anypoint should never exceed 100.

Comment: yes, it is possible. what have you tried so far?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please vote up and/or mark as accepted, thx!

Comment: Paragraph 1 says: `Old records will be automatically replaced with newer ones.`   Paragraph 2:  `Newer records will be replaced with older ones.`   Can't have it both ways, I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you do not want the output to be the newest 100 records (easily to achieve with `SELECT TOP 100 [...] ORDER BY YourDateColumn`.

If you really and physically want to make sure, that the 100 newest records are stored and the rest is deleted, you should use a trigger.

Some questions: Will there be more than one user (sessions) which manipulate this table? Will the "newest" change only by `INSERT` or could an older record become a newer one by `UPDATE` too?

But I would think about this! If you do not have a really good reason to do this, I would NEVER go like this...

You should never try to delete a record physically another session could still rely on.

What I would do:

Use a "TOP 100"-View to achieve your goal and a regularely running job to throw away older records with some hangover periode.

Answer (score 1):

In such case you can use trigger

CREATE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on [Plan] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN

declare @count int v
select @count=COUNT(*) from [Plan]

if(@count<=0)

begin
  disable trigger InsteadTrigger

INSERT INTO [Plan] 
       Color=Color 
       FROM inserted

enable trigger InsteadTrigger 
  end 
  else 
   begin 
   declare @LastId int 
   select @LastId=COUNT(LastId) from [Plan] 
/*LastID will be an extra column to maintain the history of last so that you can update next column */

    update [Plan] set Color=Color,LastId=@LastId+1  where Id=Id 
   end
  
END